# Adding a CSS Stylesheet to Pycharm using {% static %}. Error 404 Not Found

Tags: html, css, pycharm

After following the exact steps the instructor took on a prerecorded online course, I find myself stuck trying to understand this error I'm receiving. Or rather an issue in my code that is preventing me from getting the same results as the instructor.

On Pycharm, he created a file "index.html" under a directory titled "menu", which is under another directory titled templates. He then proceeded to create a separate file "style.css" under a directory titled "menu", which is also under another directory titled "static". I presume that since this code is done in Pycharm and not in VS Code, that may be why he is using the `{% load static %}` notation.

The code is as scripted in the text below... I believe the issue is in the

```
"""href="{% static 'menu/style.css'%}"\>"""
```

The CSS code under that HTML code shows the CSS style instruction which is failing to yield the "blue" colour result.

```
{% load static %}

<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Our Pizzas</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'menu/style.css'%}">
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Our Pizzas</h1>

    <ul>
        {% for pizza in pizzas %}
        <li>{{pizza.name}} : ${{pizza.price}}</li>
        {% endfor %}
    </ul>
</body>
</html>

<!-- css Code -->
h1, li {
    color: blue;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Apologies! Turns out, I was using the wrong browser for the task. Microsoft Edge wasn't able to complete the task. Chrome and Firefox work just fine.